# cp command removing files

Tags: 18.04, cp

I am attempting to copy a directory with many directories inside it. I am using `cp -v -R source /mnt/dest`. When I go back to the source all the files are missing, but the folder is there.  I am copying to a mounted network drive which doesn't receive all the files or directories. I have to restore the data on the source and start over.  Anything I can check or maybe a different argument?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Well it's definitely not expected behaviour. Is the source drive failing? If you do a copy from the source drive to itself, and a copy from the destination drive to itself, do they both succeed? What is the exact command you're using?

Comment: Maybe you're not running /bin/cp like you think you are.  Try the command which cp  to see if some script is being run from a path earlier than /bin in your $PATH.  Check your aliases.

Comment: The output of `type -a cp` might be useful - at least we can eliminate some far fetched possibilities

Comment: Show us some of the output produced by `cp -v`.

Comment: @wjandrea Source drive has not issues that i'm aware of.

sudo cp -v -R Tv\ shows/ /mnt/networkdisk  

Network disk is mounted, I force mount before I started copying.

Comment: @waltinator 


'Tv shows/House MD' -> '/mnt/networkdisk/Tv shows/House MD'
'Tv shows/House MD/House MD S01 BR HEVC D3FiL3R (no subs)' -> '/mnt/networkdisk/Tv shows/House MD/House MD S01 BR HEVC D3FiL3R (no subs)'

Comment: @pctech5510 Please [edit] your question to add details. Terminal output can't be formatted properly in comments.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and issues with the comments.  Found the issue at hand. The destination disk was bad with many bad sectors, and causing data loss on both sides. I replaced the drive, remounted, and it is running as intended.
Thank you all